# Is it possible to highlight html element in Webview on mouse hover?

Tags: c#, dom, mvvm, winrt-xaml, highlight

Well, the title actually is clear already for what I want to know. Just to clarify what I mean: I wonder if it is possible to do functionality simillar to those of Firebug and F12 Developer Tools in Internet Explorer.

[Picture explaining what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skcrd.png)

It doesn't matter which way around would it be highlighted. In principle I am just curious if it is possible to highliht the element on hover.

Right now I'm more interested if it is possible to achieve this with Visual Studio 2015, runing WinRT (Windows 8.1) C# project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found this http://selectorgadget.com/. Seems like something I could use. Would I be able to inject this tool to my own WinRT application?

Comment: Should be possible by injecting JavaScript functions for that

Comment: Here is a very old example I wrote: http://irisclasson.com/2012/10/12/how-to-invoke-javascript-functions-in-a-webview-in-windows-store-apps/ Use it at most as a vague guide, the platform has undergone a lot of changes since then.